# Create new model instance with array inside

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following model settings:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    areas: [{
        area: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            enum: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        }
    }],
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

module.exports = Item;
```

When I try to save an instance in the DB:

```
const item = new Item({
    areas: [1, 2, 3],
});

item.save();
```

I get the following error:

```
Item validation failed: areas: Cast to embedded failed for value "1" at path "areas"

CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "1" at path "areas"
```

Why do I get this error? I can't find what Schema rule I broke..

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are setting the areas as an array of objects that contains area property, like:

```
[{area: 1}, {area: 2}, {area: 3}]
```

Maybe you could try set it as:

```
areas: [{
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            enum: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }],
```